# How is transaction managed in Django's admin commands?

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I just wonder how is transaction managed in django's admin commands. Commit on save? Commit on success? I can't find related info from official documents.

Answer (score 5):

Management command operations are not wrapped in transactions unless you tell them to.

You can tell the **handle()** method to be wrapped in a transaction by setting the **output_transaction** attribute to True. From the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/custom-management-commands/#django.core.management.BaseCommand.output_transaction):

> **BaseCommand.output_transaction**
>
> A boolean indicating whether the command outputs SQL statements; if True, the output will automatically be wrapped with BEGIN; and COMMIT;. Default value is False.

For more control you can always initiate transactions yourself:

```
...
def handle(self, *args, **options):
    with transaction.atomic():
        do_your_stuff()
```

Comment: Adding `output_transaction = True` didn't work for me (DB changes persisted even when code in `handle()` raised an error) but initiating the transaction manually as per your second suggestion worked fine. I also found this template for a transaction-controlled command: https://gist.github.com/marcoala/a176ee0e75771a826a1197cc69336580

Comment: What type of database is this with?

Comment: MariaDB 10.3.12-10.

Comment: For future reference: I recently got my hopes up about `output_transaction` as well, but it turns out it's only about any _printed_ SQL output, not about the actual queries that might be performed in the command. Looking at the django internal commands (always interesting) is seems only `loaddata` uses a transaction, with the wrapper described in this answer.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not too sure, but admin forms don't reach to the commit point unless they meet clean() requirements. After that I guess everything will be committed. This behavior should be sufficient for the default forms in admin. However, for more complex forms, you can create your custom admin form and I'm pretty sure you can define whether or not you want to commit on success or on save.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not talking about Admin site but admin commands: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-management-commands/

Comment: My bad, for admin commands, most likely transactions are committed on save() just like the default behavior in views.